# How to map json entities?

Tags: json, react-native

There is a way to map json objects in react-native? For example, let's say I receive the following object:

```
{
    "dados": {
        "ultimaAtualizacao": {
            "nome": "Lala"
        }
        "nascimento": "01/01/2001"
    }
}
```

I want to map it like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "lastUpdate": {
            "name": "Lala"
        }
        "dob": "01/01/2001"
    }
}
```

Considering that `fetch` returns the first object, this would be possible doing the following code:

```
myService.get(url).then(response => this.mapObject(response, []));

//Considering state is initialized and I have the mapedEntity to return correct properties
mapObject(jsonObject, parentProperty) {
    for (let property in jsonObject) {
        if (Array.isArray(jsonObject[property])) {
            this.mapArray(jsonObject[property], [...parentProperty,property]); //Would be something like mapObject function
        } else if (typeof jsonObject[property] === 'object') {
            this.mapObject(jsonObject[property],[...parentProperty,property]);
        } else {
            let prop = this.state;
            for(let k of parentProperty) {
              prop = prop[mapedEntity[k]];
            }
            prop[entidadeMapeada[property]] = jsonObject[property];
        }
    }
}
```

There is someway simplier to achieve this?